# Values replaced with na, are still shown in summary()

Tags: r, tidyr

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
# Packages used
pkg <- c("tidyverse",
         "synthpop"
)

tmp1 <- read_csv2(file1)
tmp2 <- read_csv2(file2) 
tmp <- tmp1 %>%
    left_join(tmp2)
```

I had the problem that there were both na's values and textual NA values (which came from the csv file). To solve this problem I replaced the text NA's with actual na's see below.

```
# replacing textual "NA"'s with actual na's that are regonized by R 
tmp <- na_if(tmp, "NA")
```

However when running:

```
summary(tmp["Region"])
```

Output:

```
Region      
 North:19342  
 West :91234  
 East :48001  
 South:43347  
 NA   :    0  
 NA's :12276
```

It still shows textual NA as a category, although with count 0 (it does so for all variables in tmp). I run into problems because of this, later in my code. I would want that the textual NA does not exist anymore (its not about the output, but about the actual existence of NA as a factor, i synthesize the dataset later on, and the NA and NA's should not be taken as two seperate possibilities).

What is an alternative or addition to: `tmp <- na_if(tmp, "NA")`, so that this problem would not occur? I hope you can help me!

Comment: To help, we _really_ need to see your data.  Please supply the output from `dput(tmp)` or `dput(head(tmp))`.

Comment: is region a `factor` with a level called "NA"? what happens with `summary(droplevels(tmp["Region"]))`

Comment: I unfortunately cant show any data because of regulations.

Comment: The droplevels does unfortunately not work as it's not about the summary output. The output merely shows that the NA is still a different category than NA's which brings problems later on.

Comment: @RomySchipper If you can't share the data create something with the same logic/structure but with made up data.

Comment: How did you use `droplevels` ? Try `tmp <- droplevels(tmp)` and then do `summary(tmp["Region"])`. What does that give you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forcats::fct_drop` will remove unused levels in a factor:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~a, "a", "b", "c", "NA", NA) %>% 
  mutate(a = as_factor(a))

df2 <- na_if(df, "NA") %>% 
  mutate(a = fct_drop(a))

summary(df2)
#>     a    
#>  a   :1  
#>  b   :1  
#>  c   :1  
#>  NA's:2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The `base::droplevels` function suggested above in comments does the same of course! I quite like the `forcats` package for getting used to handling factors and levels though.